# Sending up a list of objects on a create form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view specific model that combines a few of my objects together but I was having a few issues with a list of objects.

My model is so:

```
public class RouteSubcontract
{
    public RoutingSubcontracts Subcontracts { get; set; }
    public RoutingPhases Phases { get; set; }
    public List<RoutingApprovals> Approvals { get; set; }
}
```

I have my create form and everything is working correctly, I am using html helpers like so:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Subcontracts.subRevNbr, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "textReplace", @id = "frmRevNbr" } })
```

But the problem is when I need to have the list of approvals, I am not even sure how to start with this.  I need the ability to create a list of items, I can with jquery have a button that then creates the row of textboxes I need to enter the data, but I am unsure how to ID or name them so that they are picked up correctly by my post back.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AdminRoutingCreate(RouteSubcontract rs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For collections the modelbinder expects inputs named in the following format: `ListProperty[Index].Property`. For example, if you wanted to edit a property on `RoutingApprovals` named `Foo`, you're need something like:

```
<input type="text" name="Approvals[0].Foo" />
<input type="text" name="Approvals[1].Foo" />
<input type="text" name="Approvals[2].Foo" />
```

On post back you'd end up with three `RoutingApprovals` instances.